# Android studio always report a error about BR.class

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, gradle

I am using data-binding to develop android app. And the gradle plugin i use is the latest(1.5.0). But when i use the `BR.class` which data-binding generated, Android Studio always report a error. But compilation can be success both in Android studio and command line.

Here is the screenshot of this error:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @GeorgeMount Android studio version: 1.4.1
gradle plugin version: 1.5.0
data-binding.: 1.0-rc5

Comment: But it's very strange. Today  it seems ok, i have done nothing to my project.

Comment: Same issue. For me, it works sometimes after restarting in the studio.